# Should the <description> and <ExtendedData> nodes be exclusive?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am Loading a `KML` file with a `Placemark` into `Google Earth`, when I include both the description and `ExtendedData` nodes, only the description is displayed in the balloon.

If I remove the description, and change nothing else, then the `ExtendedData` is displayed.  I have found nothing in the `KML` Reference or the `KML` Schema to indicate this is the expected behavior.  Presumably, at least as far as `Google Earth` is concerned, I'll have to resort to specifying a `<BalloonStyle>` in order to pull the `ExtendedData` into the description.

Can anyone confirm or dispute that this is the intended behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is the undocumented intended behavior in Google Earth.

Answer (score 0):

If a KML feature has no description but has [ExtendedData](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#extendeddata) then Google Earth will auto-format the ExtendedData contents in a print-friendly HTML table. If a feature has a description then it will be used regardless whether or not ExtendedData is present.

Some details about this behavior can be found in the [KML Errata](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#ExtendedDataLimit).

If you want to custom format the ExtendedData elements then you must specify a [BalloonStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle) and apply that to each Placemark with styleUrl. More details can be found in a related help article: [Adding Custom Data](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata).